# TSQL Pivot with combination result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have data in SQL server 2005 table similar to below format.

```
OrderNo ProductId Sale
----------------------
1          A    £10
2          B    £20
3          C    £30
4          A    £10
4          B    £20
5          A    £10
5          B    £20
6          C    £30
6          B    £20
7          C    £30
```

I need to write TSQL  query that would give me result table  in this format.

```
NoOfOrders     'A' SaleValue 'B' SaleValue  'C' SaleValue
------------------------------------------------
Prod A (Only)   1   £10     
Prod B (Only)   1               £20 
Prod C (Only)   2                             £60
Prod A & B      2   £20         £40 
Prod A & C      0   £0          £0             £0
Prod B & C      1               £20            £30
```

Any idea greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the result for only these 3 products or will you have an unlimited number of products?

Comment: I only need it for 3 products Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a three-step approach:

(1) SELECT distinct ProductID into a table variable.
(2) CROSS JOIN the table variable on itself to get all possible combinations.
(3) Craft a dynamic SQL statement to pivot it out.